# How do I tell to Firefox that it's fine for a div to span multiple columns?

Tags: html, css, firefox, multiple-columns, css-multicolumn-layout

On [a page](https://blog.pelicandd.com/), I use a layout where the text is positioned in two columns when the page is large enough. This works well in Chromium, but not in Firefox.

The content is structured like this:

```html
<main style="columns: 2;">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <div>Date, author, and other stuff.</div>
    <div>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
         ⋮
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

As the last `<div>` contains most of the content, Chromium puts the `<h1>`, the first `<div>`, and the beginning of the last `<div>` on the first column, and the remaining part of the last `<div>` on the second column (Fig. 1). Firefox 90.0.2, however, moves the entire last `<div>` to a second column (Fig. 2).

I noticed that if I remove the last `<div>`, putting all the paragraphs as direct children of `<main>`, Firefox starts showing the content similarly to Chromium. However, I would prefer keeping the DOM as it is now, and rather understand why Firefox is behaving the way it does.

- What's the reason for this behavior in Firefox?
- How should I change the CSS in order to have in Firefox a similar behavior to what I get in Chromium, while keeping the actual structure of the nodes?

[image]

**Fig­ure 1** Chromium showing the columns as I expect them to be shown.

[image]

**Fig­ure 2** Firefox moving the whole article body to the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `p` elements are nested inside of the `div`. You can use `display: contents` for the `div.content` to force browser to *ignore its hierarchy*.

> **contents**
> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate boxes and text runs as normal.
>
> Source: [2.5. Box Generation: the none and contents keywords | w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents)

Example based on your website:

```css
main {
   columns: 2;
}

.content {
   display: contents;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <div>Date, author, and other stuff.</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</main>
```